# Numpy array item order - equal distribution of sequences

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, random, graph-theory

Lets say I have a shuffled numpy array:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]*6)
np.random.shuffle(a)
```

How do I ensure that each item in the shuffled array follows each other item an equal number of times?

For example, I want to ensure that the number 1 follows the number 2 in the array the same number of times as it follows the number 4. Likewise for all other numbers

We can assume that the list is circular for this problem, i.e., the first item follows the last

Normally I'd post some code of what I've tried but I'm at a loss when it comes to this.

The most inefficient way I can think of is to write a function that counts how many times a number follows another number, and then to check that all counts are equal. If not, reshuffle.

But this doesn't guarantee that I'll ever end up with a list that meets the equal distribution criteria.

Comment: What you want is mathematically impossible. You have 36 numbers and only 35 "followings."

Comment: Is there a minimum array length that will allow this? Or will we always be 1 short?

Comment: The first number follows nothing, so you are one short by definition of following. If you consider your list to be circular then it's possible.

Comment: makes sense, Im OK making the circular assumption for the purposes of this question

Comment: Use the permutations operator to generate all 36 possibilities?  Do you need them to still be in a random order?  If so, then you'll have to write the "shuffle" function; this isn't a built-in capabilit.

Comment: The primary constraint is the equality. After ensuring equality, I would like the order to be as random as possible yes, assuming there is more than 1 unique solution to this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the best that I can come up with. Note that with 36 numbers each number must follow each other number exactly once.

```
while True:
    x = {i: set(range(1,7)) for i in range(1,7)}

    a = [random.choice(range(1,7))]  # start with a random number
    last = a[-1]
    while x[last]:
        next = random.choice(list(x[last]))
        x[last].remove(next)
        a.append(next)
        last = next

    if len(a) == 37:
        # We get to length 37 if and only if each set above is exhausted.
        # In this case, the first item will always equal the last item
        # (proof left as an exercise for the reader), so remove it.
        a = a[:-1]
        break

print(''.join(str(i) for i in a))
```

which for me, produces `221164425231355145433465615366263241` which seems to satisfy the criteria.